# Vue-Bootstrap: how to trigger sorting of one b-table to trigger sorting of the another b-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vue-events

I'm using [VueBoostrap](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) `<b-table>` components, in a combination with [sorting routine applied](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#sort-compare-routine). In my project I have some more complex sorting routine, but for this dummy example, I will use the default one.

When a sorting is applied for a b-table, the table is simply sorted based on the clicked field in the table header. But what I need to achieve is to split the table header from the table content (since I want to place the content in a scrollable div later, while the header to remain static at the top - as user will be scrolling).

The complete code is given [on this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxv19p8njv) (check `componets/TableTest.vue`), where I have three `<b-table>` components. First one is just a dummy example, and the next two are identical as the first one, but for one of them the header is hidden and for the other the body is hidden.

What I want to achieve is:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a close look at the docs (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table) you can see that there are certain events emitted by the `<b-table>` component.
One of them is `sort-changed`. So if you listen for that on your header only component and then set a `sortBy` property that you pass into the body only component you're all set.

```
//header only
<b-table ... @sort-changed="sortChanged">

// body only
<b-table :sort-by="sortBy" ...>

sortChanged(e) {
  this.sortBy = e.sortBy
}
```

Full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/y30x78oz81

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the OP is asking :

"How do I force a `<b-table>` component to (re)sort itself without requiring the user to click on that `<b-table>` component?"

My answer (in their case):

1. Detect the click event on the "visible header" mentioned
2. In the function handler for that click event, emit a `sort-changed` event from the target table

```
// Assuming an SFC (single file component)

<template>
<div>
<b-button @click="handleClick">Sort the table!</b-button>

<b-table ref="mytable" @sort-changed="handleSortChange"></b-table>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  // ...

  methods: {

    handleClick(evt) {
      /// this is called when you click the button
      this.$refs.mytable.$emit('sort-changed')
    }

handleSortChange(context) {
      // this is called when b-table with ref "mytable" hears the 'sort-changed' event
      // that it has emitted

      // sorting logic goes here
    }
  }
  //...
}


</script>
```